# How many polynomials of degree $m$ are there in $\mathbb Z_n[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Write all quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. How many cubic polynomials are there in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$? More generally, how many polynomials of degree $m$ are there in $\mathbb Z_n[x]$?

So quadratic polynomials have degree 2 so:
$x^2 +x +1,x^2 +x +2,x^2 +x +3, x^2 +x +4, 2x^2 +x +1, 2x^2 +x +2,2x^2 +x +3, 3x^2 +3x +3, 4x^2 +4x +4...$ so on and so forth. Will this be the comprehensive list?

Now, I am under the impression there will be just as many cubic polynomials. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean "how many *irreducible* polynomials are there"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have listed the question how it was asked of me. I don't believe so because I have not yet learned about being irreducible though I know that is coming up.

Answer (score 3):

A polynomial of degree $m$ has $m+1$ terms. The leading term is not zero and the remaining $m$ terms can have any coefficient. So it is
$$(n-1)n^m$$

For $m=2$ and $n=5$ this gives $100$ polynomials, a bit too many to write them all.